# How can I get the absolute path of the currently running test?

Tags: jestjs

I have a case where it's necessary to find the path of the currently executing path. Does this exist anywhere in Jest?

Answer (score 0):

Did some digging and found that it's available on the global scope as `jasmine.testPath` (at least on version 23.4.2, but presumably as long as Jasmine is handling test runs under the hood)